# Format negative integer/double using sprintf

Tags: c++, char, string-formatting, printf, negative-number

is it possible using only sprintf (c++) to format a negative integer/double in a way that there is a space between the sign and the value?

```
from this: -1234

to this: - 1234
```

Edit: It will go in a char array.

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, why do you want this format? Do some countries format negative numbers with a space before the digits?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about what you can and can't do... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @Bojangles: I have definitely seen reports which had a leading sign for both positive and negative numbers with the signs aligned.

Comment: I'm programming a type of translator which transforms g-code files read by modern CNC machines into an older format which can be read by older machines. These older machines read negative values like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that this isn't the question but since this is tagged as C++:

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << std::internal << std::setw(6) << -1234;
std::string result = out.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sprintf`? **[Not directly, no](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).**

You would need to implement this logic yourself (using `abs`/`fabs` and a second `sprintf` argument), or use the appropriate *locale* for the country who uses this rendering layout and hope that your implementation abides by it.

It would probably be a lot easier with C++'s own I/O streams, so consider switching to those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char large_evil_array[128];
double my_var = -12.34;
int my_int = -6589;
int chars_formatted = 
    snprintf(large_evil_array, sizeof(large_evil_array),
             "%c %5.2f %c %d\n",
              (char)((my_var < 0) ? '-' : ' '),
              (double)((my_var < 0) ? (my_var * -1.0) : my_var),
              (char)((my_int < 0) ? '-' : ' '),
              (int)((my_int < 0) ? (-1 * my_int) : my_int));
```

If you used C++ streams, you could write your own formatting modifier.